# Как вывести только 1 последние значение

Tags: python

Задача: Пользователь делает вклад в размере N рублей сроком на years лет под 10% годовых (каждый год размер его вклада увеличивается на 10%. Эти деньги прибавляются к сумме вклада и на них в следующем году тоже будут проценты).
Написать функцию bank, принимающую аргументы N и years, и возвращающую сумму, которая будет на счету пользователя.

```
def bank():
    stavka = 10
    n = int(input("Сколько у Вас денег?""\n""-> "))
    years = int(input("На сколько лет хотите сделать вклад?""\n""-> "))

    for i in range(years):
        n = int(n+stavka*n/100)
        print("По итогу вы получаете", n, "рублей")
bank()
```

Выдает значения за каждый год, а мне нужно выводить только последние значение.

```
Сколько у Вас денег?
-> 1221
На сколько лет хотите сделать вклад?
-> 5
По итогу вы получаете 1343 рублей
По итогу вы получаете 1477 рублей
По итогу вы получаете 1624 рублей
По итогу вы получаете 1786 рублей
По итогу вы получаете 1964 рублей
```

Переделал на:

```
def bank():
    stavka = 0.1
    n = int(input("Сколько у Вас денег?""\n""-> "))
    years = int(input("На сколько лет хотите сделать вклад?""\n""-> "))

    x = n*(1+stavka)**years
    print("По итогу вы получаете", x , "рублей")
bank()
```

Comment: Просто бы `print` из цикла `for` вынес и всё сработало бы :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Общая сумма, которую получит вкладчик, при расчёте по сложному проценту будет равна

x*(1+a)^n

где x — начальная сумма вложенных средств,  a — годовая процентная ставка, n — срок вклада в годах.

Называется "Сложные проценты". К Python отношения не имеет от слова совсем.

P.S. Кстати, переводя на каждом шаге результат в int вы существенно накапливаете результирующую ошибку своего ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
def bank(money,years):

    for i in range(years):
        money = (money + (money / 10))
    return money 
    
print(bank(1000,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def bank():
    m = int(input('sum '))
    y = int(input('let '))
    for i in range(y):
        m += int(m * 0.1)
    return m
print(bank())
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```py
def bank(a, years):

    if a < 0 or a == 0:

        print("Нельзя так !")
        return

    if years < 0 or years == 0:
        print("Нельзя так !")
    else:
        result = a*0.1 * years
    summa = a + result
    print("Ваш счет через", years, "года будет:", summa)

    a = int(input("Сколько денег хотите вложить:"))
    years = int(input("На сколько лет?"))
    bank(a, years)
```

А если так?